# Stubbing result of Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a funciton that calls Net::HTTP.new(google_url.host, google_url.port) and I am trying to figure out how to stub the result for testing. Basically I don't want to be hitting the google URL shortener every time I run my test.

```
 def shorten_url(long_url)
    google_url = URI.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url")
    data = JSON.generate({"longUrl" => "#{long_url}"})
    header = {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
    http = Net::HTTP.new(google_url.host, google_url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    short_url = ""

    res = http.request_post(google_url.path, data, header)
    jsonResponse = JSON.parse(res.body)
    short_url = jsonResponse["id"]
  end
```

Basically I want to be able to set the result of that function.

I've tried things like: `Net::HTTP.any_instance.stubs(:HTTP.new).returns("www.test.com")` but cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
class HTTP < Protocol
     ....
    # Creates a new Net::HTTP object.
    # If +proxy_addr+ is given, creates an Net::HTTP object with proxy support.
    # This method does not open the TCP connection.
    def HTTP.new(address, port = nil, p_addr = nil, p_port = nil, p_user = nil, p_pass = nil)
      h = Proxy(p_addr, p_port, p_user, p_pass).newobj(address, port)
      h.instance_eval {
        @newimpl = ::Net::HTTP.version_1_2?
      }
      h
    end
....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) - this sounds like it will do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Because of the nature of the app, I need to do it without installing any gems. Thank you though.